# Equation for Velocity of air and Pressure difference

Tags: pressure, velocity, air

Whenever there is a pressure difference, air will flow from the high pressure (area/point) to low pressure (area/point).

I am looking for the equation that relates the velocity of air to the pressure difference of the air between two points.

Comment: Search Bernoulli's principle

Comment: On what scale do you consider this phenomena? Like a physical lab scale or like a synoptic meteorological scale? As  Coriolis fictitious force can be neglected for the former while playing a major role in the latter. // In small scale, pressure gradient is related to air acceleration, not speed. // In large scale, velocity vector does not follow the direction of pressure gradient vector, but can be even perpendicular to it. (some 10-15 deviation degrees at sea, 30-40 degrees at ground, 90 degrees above the air/surface friction layer.